# Get SecTrustEvaluate to trust my self signed certificate

Tags: ios, security, openssl

I am generating a certificate like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem
```

I want secTrustEvaluate to pass when I send in the key. I am converting the cert.pem to a SecTrustRef. Then I am adding it to the list of anchor certificates like so:

```
SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly(trustRef, true);
```

My question is if I then do:

```
SecTrustEvaluate(trustRef);
```

It is currently evaluating to false, which I believe is correct. All I want is to be able to create a certificate, then get that certificate to evaluate true via SecTrustEvaluate. Is this possible, or do I have to get my certificate signed by a CA? Note, this is just for testing that my SSL certificate validator is working.

Comment: `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly` uses the built-in CA store. See [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html). Since your cert is not signed by a built-in CA, its going to fail. For a list of built-in CAs, see [iOS: List of available trusted root certificates](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012).

Comment: @jww: Sorry, I'm not totally following. So I have to get my certA signed by a built-in CA? Let's say that CertA is signed by a built-in CA, then if I do this, and use SecTrustEvaluate(certB), then certB will be evaluated only against certA, or against every anchor cert?

Comment: See [Overriding TLS Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html) from the Apple docs.